# What does it mean to evaluate a polynomial at a linear map, e.g. $p(T)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm learning about the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem and the Primary Decomposition Theorem, and have trouble understanding what the notations mean. What does $\chi_T(T)$ mean? ($\chi_T(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial.)

I guess just like how we defined $\chi_T=\chi_A$, I can think of it as evaluating at $A= {}_B[T]_B$ with respect to some basis $B$. However, wouldn't $\chi_T(T)$ be different depending on what basis you choose in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing they mean that you represent the whole polynomial by matrices and then plug in $T$. But this notation should be avoided and the wikipedia page describes why pretty well if I remember correctly. [here's the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: A polynomial makes sense in any algebra (where you have addition, scalar multiplication, and "vector" multiplication). Matrices make one of these. So just replace the powers in the polynomial with matrix powers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. If $V$ is a $k$-vector space, and $T\in\mathrm{End}(V)$ is some $k$-linear map $T:V\to V$, then the polynomial
$$p=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n\in k[x]$$
evaluated at $T$ is just
$$a_0+a_1T+\cdots + a_nT^n\in\mathrm{End}(V)$$
where $T^k$ is $T$ composed with itself $k$ times, and $aT$ is the element of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ defined by
$$(aT)(v)=a\cdot T(V)$$

---

Here is a more abstract take on things. It is easy to check that the collection of all linear maps $T:V\to V$, denoted by $\mathrm{End}(V)$, is a (non-commutative) ring, where addition is pointwise addition:
$$(T_1+T_2)(v):=T_1(v)+T_2(v)$$
and multiplication is composition:
$$(T_1\cdot T_2)(v):=T_1(T_2(v))$$
Now choose some particular $T\in\mathrm{End}(V)$. By the universal property of the polynomial ring $k[x]$, we can define a ring homomorphism $k[x]\to\mathrm{End}(V)$ by simply declaring that $x$ should go to $T$; everything else about how the homomorphism acts is then determined. The result is the evaluation homomorphism
$$\mathrm{ev}_T:k[x]\to\mathrm{End}(V),\qquad \mathrm{ev}_T(p)=p(T)$$

Comment: It may be misleading to talk about the universal property of the polynomial ring because evaluation does not typically respect multiplication for noncommutative rings. In this special case, evaluation is indeed a ring homomorphism because the coefficients map to $k$-multiples of $\mathrm{Id}_V$, which commute with $T$.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomial rings are characterized by [a universal property](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_21.pdf) which ensures that this makes sense.

Let $k$ be a field and let $V$ be a $k$-vector space. Then the collection of endomorphisms of $V$ ($k$-linear maps from $V$ to itself) forms a ring, $\text{End}_k(V)$, with pointwise addition and composition as multiplication. Given any transformation $T\in \text{End}_k(V)$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\epsilon_T:k[x]\rightarrow \text{End}_k(V)$ sending constant polynomials to corresponding scalar transformations and sending the indeterminate $x$ to $T$. This is called the *evaluation map* for $T$.

The "evaluation" of a polynomial $p\in k[x]$ at $T\in \text{End}_k(V)$ is by definition $\epsilon_T(p)$, and it is often denoted by "$p(T)$".

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix representing a transformation $T$ does not depend on the choice of basis.

In particular: for any basis $C$ and a fixed basis $B$, we have $[T]_C = S[T]_BS^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $S$.  We then have
$$
\det([T]_C - tI) = 
\det(S[T]_BS^{-1} - tI) = 
\det(S([T]_B-tI)S^{-1}) = \\
\det(S)\det([T]_B-tI)\det(S^{-1}) = 
\det([T]_B - tI)
$$